# Base Href and Rewrite conflict?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, radix

I have a site that was developed outside of the root directory, and now that I've designated the /site/ folder as the root via .htaccess in the real root, I cannot seem to remove the folder from the URL address.

```
<base href="/site/">
```

Then in /site/ .htaccess

```
# Rewrite path to remove /site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /site/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, though I'm guessing `<base href="">` is adding it after the .htaccess has processed?

Is there anyway around this (or is my rewrite just wrong)?

Comment: Pretty please with a cherry for an answer.

Comment: The HTML tag knows nothing of the server file structure. If you are trying to hide the fact that the site is in a site subfolder, then you definitely don't want that base URL tag to be set it to the subfolder. You also need to put the .htaccess file in the web root folder, not in the site subfolder.

Comment: I had to use the base tag because of pretty URL rewrites (it wasn't loading subfolders properly). I would much prefer not using it but without it the site doesn't work properly. Also, there are 2 .htaccess files - the one in the root points it to the site folder and the one in the site folder removes query strings and makes the 'pretty URLs'. Thanks for confirming it's the `<base>` tag causing it. Sounds like I'm stuck :/

Comment: The base tag only makes it work because you don't have rewriting working yet. Once you get the rewrite rules working, then the base tag must go away. Also, on your rewrite rule, there should be no slash before /site/$1. It should be site/$1.

Comment: I see. So the choices are 1) Rewrite the rewrites because I messed up somewhere in that voodoo, 2) fix the absolute/relative path issue that likely caused the need for the base tag, or 3), drop everything in the real root and fix the relative paths.

Available for some Apache work? lol 

Thanks for the help. If you're interested I'd be happy to pay, just not sure how to contact on here..